# Escribir un programa que pida un número entero al usuario y calcule su raíz cuadrada utilizando Math.sqrt ()

Tags: java, bucles, excepciones

yo soy un estudiante de informática y estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java. Tenía una duda sobre un ejercicio, que a lo mejor es una tontería pero que yo no se resolver.

El enunciado del ejercicio es el siguiente:

```
 Escribir un programa que pida un número entero al usuario y calcule su raíz cuadrada
utilizando Math.sqrt ().
Agregar SÓLO un bloque "catch" para tratar los siguientes errores:
- El usuario introduzca un número negativo,
- El usuario introduzca una palabra.
Se debe tratar el error mostrando un misstage de error común y pedir de nuevo el
número.
El procedimiento se acabará cuando el usuario introduzca un número correcto o haya
Demant el número tres veces.
```

Yo he hecho el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumeroNegativoException{
        int numAux;

        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean condicion=false;
        do {
            condicion=false;
            try {

                System.out.println("Introduce un numero por pantalla");
                numAux = teclado.nextInt();
                teclado.nextLine();

                if (numAux < 0) {
                    throw new NumeroNegativoException("Error: el numero no puede ser negativo");
                }

                System.out.println("la raiz cuadrada de " + numAux + " es " + Math.sqrt(numAux));
            } catch (NumeroNegativoException | InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: no es posible introducir un numero negativo o una palabra.");
                condicion=true;
            }
        }while(condicion==true);
    }
}
```

```
public class NumeroNegativoException extends Exception {
    public NumeroNegativoException(String mensaje){
        super(mensaje);
    }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa e introduzco un numero entero positivo, me hace la raíz cuadrada sin problema. Si escribo un numero negativo, salta la excepción y te pide otro numero por pantalla. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando escribo una palabra, salta la excepción en el catch y te pide otro numero, haciéndolo infinitas veces todo el rato en bucle sin parar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, no se cual es el error. Si alguien me pudiese aclarar la duda se lo agradecería de verdad. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el javadoc de [Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int.
> An invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default radix of this scanner.

Mirando [Scanner.nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int))

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

Es decir, lo que hay en el buffer solo se consume si no se lanza la excepción. Pero después de procesar la excepción, tú siguiente invocación es al método *nextInt()* de Scanner.

En este caso tocaría separar la causa de la excepción, y hacer un *Scanner.next()* para limpiar el token que está "en espera". Yo lo haría separando los catchs (aunque hay otras opciones)

```
        } catch (NumeroNegativoException nne) {
            System.out.println("Error: Debe introducir un número positivo.");
            condicion=true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: Debe introducir un número positivo.");
            teclado.next();
            condicion=true;
        }
    } while (condicion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te entra en bucle infinito porque la excepción de InputMismatchException se generaría cuando la clase Scanner lee, es decir cuando inicializas la variable teclado, y al no estar dentro del catch no se maneja la excepción. Por otro lado, no deberías elevar la excepción,  jamás por encima del main ya que es la clase principal.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private  static Scanner teclado;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numAux;

   
    boolean condicion=false;
    do {
        condicion=false;
        try {
             teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero por pantalla");
            numAux = teclado.nextInt();
            
            

            if (numAux < 0) {
                throw new NumeroNegativoException("Error: el numero no puede ser negativo");
            }

            System.out.println("la raiz cuadrada de " + numAux + " es " + Math.sqrt(numAux));
        } catch (NumeroNegativoException | InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: no es posible introducir un numero negativo o una palabra.");
            condicion=true;
        }
    }while(condicion==true);
}
}
```